# Is it possible to modify soil pH with plants?

Tags: soil-amendment, ph

I have a very chalky soil and I'd like to decrease its pH.

Are there plants that can effectively help correct the soil pH permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no, it isn't possible to alter your soil's ph by growing particular plants - if your soil is chalky, choose alkaline loving plants to grow in it and avoid acid lovers, or grow those in pots in acid potting soil  (ericaceous planting soil).

Soil profiles and their acidity are largely determined by geography or area, that is, what underlies the soil, so if its chalk or limestone, then the soil will be alkaline.